# Import error for openzeppelin

Tags: contract-development, dapps, openzeppelin

I have tried both

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

import "openzeppelin/contracts/math/Math.sol";
```

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/math/Math.sol";
```

Getting an error for both codes ( I already have installed the openzappelin).
`Error: Could not find openzeppelin/contracts/math/Math.sol from any sources`
How can I use the openzappelin packages in the smart contract?

Comment: are you sure you have OpenZeppelin in your `node_modules`?

Comment: I have openzeppelin-solidity in node_modules.

Comment: `npm install @openzeppelin/contracts` then
`import "@openzeppelin/contracts/math/Math.sol";`

Comment: that's strange... does the issue persist if you import `SafeMath.sol` instead?

Comment: On second thought, I wonder if your version of Solidity is the issue - is there a specific reason you're using Solidity 0.5.0, and not 0.6?

Comment: I am using 0.5.0

Comment: @AdamBoudjemaa I have tried the same as you mentioned but not working.

Comment: is there a reason not to use Solidity 0.6 (or 0.7)? I suspect this is the issue (that the 3.x contracts use Solidity 6), but haven't been able to verify

Comment: No, as there is no reason to use 0.5.x, but with openzeppelin 3.x i am not able to find the ownable.sol